# *-homomorphisms on $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ implemented by measurable maps

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\nu)$ be two probability measure spaces. To any   measurable map $T:(X,\mu)\to (Y,\nu)$ with $\mu=\nu\circ T$, the following  injective $*$-homomorphism is induced:
$$\rho_T:L^{\infty}(Y,\nu)\to L^{\infty}(X,\mu)~~:~~\rho_T(f)=f\circ T$$ 
satisfying  in $\int f d\nu=\int f\circ T d\mu$.

The converse is also true. I am looking  for a clean proof.
This fact is mentioned in ([enter link description here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/OElectures.pdf)) Theorem 1.1.1.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Proof of the converse is concerned.